# How to filter text data in bash more efficiently

Tags: bash

I have data file which I need to filter with bash script, see data example:

```
name=pencils
name=apples
value=10
name=rocks
value=3
name=tables
value=6
name=beds
name=cups
value=89
```

I need to group **name value** pairs like so *apples=10*, if current line starts with name and next line starts with name, first line should be omitted entirely. So result file should look like this:

```
apples=10
rocks=3
tables=6
cups=89
```

I came with this simple solution which works but is very slow, it takes 5 min to complete for file with 2000 lines.

```sh
VALUES=$(cat input.txt)
for x in $VALUES; do
  if [[ -n $(echo $x | grep 'name=') ]]; then
    name=$(echo $x | sed "s/name=//")
  elif [[ -n $(echo $x | grep 'value=') ]]; then
    value=$(echo $x | sed "s/value=//")
    echo "${name}=${value}" >> output.txt
  fi
done
```

I'm aware that this kind of task is not very suitable for bash, but script is already written and this is just small part of it.

How can I optimize this task in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not run any commands in subshells, it slows your script a lot. You can do everything in the current shell.

```
#! /bin/bash
while IFS== read k v ; do
    if [[ $k == name ]] ; then
        name=$v
    elif [[ $k == value ]] ; then
        printf '%s=%s\n' "$name" "$v"
    fi
done
```

Comment: From 5min down to 0.2s. Works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

There are three easy optimizations you can make that will greatly speed up the script without requiring a major rethink.

#### 1. Replace `for` with `while read`

Loading `input.txt` into a string, and then looping over that string with `for x in $VALUES` is slow. It requires the whole file to be read into memory even though this task could be done in a streaming fashion, reading a line at a time.

A common replacement for `for line in $(cat file)` is `while read line; do ... done < file`. It turns out that loops are compound commands, and like the normal one-line commands we're used to, compound commands can have `<` and `>` redirections. Redirecting a file into a loop means that for the duration of the loop, stdin comes from the file. So if you call `read line` inside the loop then it will read one line each iteration.

```
while IFS= read -r x; do
  if [[ -n $(echo $x | grep 'name=') ]]; then
    name=$(echo $x | sed "s/name=//")
  elif [[ -n $(echo $x | grep 'value=') ]]; then
    value=$(echo $x | sed "s/value=//")
    echo "${name}=${value}" >> output.txt
  fi
done < input.txt
```

#### 2. Redirect output outside loop

It's not just input that can be redirected. We can do the same thing for the `>> output.txt` redirection. Here's where you'll see the biggest speedup. When `>> output.txt` is inside the loop `output.txt` must be opened and closed every iteration, which is crazy slow. Moving it to the outside means it only needs to be opened once. Much, much faster.

```
while IFS= read -r x; do
  if [[ -n $(echo $x | grep 'name=') ]]; then
    name=$(echo $x | sed "s/name=//")
  elif [[ -n $(echo $x | grep 'value=') ]]; then
    value=$(echo $x | sed "s/value=//")
    echo "${name}=${value}"
  fi
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

#### 3. Shell string processing

One final improvement is to use faster string processing. Calling `grep` requires forking a subprocess every time just to do a simple string split. It'd be a lot faster if we could do the string splitting using just shell constructs. Well, as it happens that's easy now that we've switched to `read`. `read` can do more than read whole lines; it can also split on a delimiter from the variable `$IFS` (inter-field separator).

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  case "$key" in
    name) name="$value";;
    value) echo "$name=$value";;
  fi
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

#### Further reading

- [BashFAQ/001 - How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
  This explains why I have `IFS= read -r` in the first two iterations.
- [BashFAQ/024 - I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)
  `cmd | while read; do ... done` is another popular use of `while read`, but it has unique pitfalls.
- [BashFAQ/100 - How do I do string manipulations in bash?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)
  More in-shell string processing options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have performance issues do not use bash at all. Use a text processing tool like, for instance, `awk`:

```sh
$ awk -F= '{name = $2} $1 == "value" {print name "=" $2}' data.txt 
apples=10
rocks=3
tables=6
cups=89
```

Explanation: `-F=` defines the field separator as character `=`. The first block is executed only if the first field of a line (`$1`) is equal to string `value`. It prints variable `name` followed by character `=` and the second field (`$2`). The second block is executed on each line and it stores the second field (`$2`) in variable `name`.

Normally, if your input resembles what you show, this should automatically skip the first line. Else, we can exclude it explicitly using a test on the `NR` variable which value is the line number, starting at 1:

```
awk -F= 'NR != 1 && $1 == "value" {print name "=" $2}
         NR != 1 {name = $2}' data.txt
```

All this works on inputs like the one you show but not on inputs where you would have other types of lines or several `value=...` consecutive lines. If you really want to test that the name/value pair is on two consecutive lines we need something more. For instance, test if the first field is `name` and use another variable `n` to store the line number of the last encountered `name=...` line. With all these tests we can now put the 2 blocks in a slightly more intuitive order (but the opposite would work the same):

```
awk -F= 'NR != 1 && $1 == "name" {name = $2; n = NR}
         NR != 1 && NR == n+1 && $1 == "value" {print name "=" $2}' data.txt
```

Comment: If I understand well, this is a procedural algorithm. Which means for the second record (we ignore the first one) the `$1 == "value"` is skipped and we only set the variable `{name = $2}`. For the third record, since the first field is `value` we just print the old recorded `name` variable and the second field. Wow, well done!

Comment: Not exactly `$1 == "value"` is executed on each line. It is the condition for the following `{...}` block. And yes, this is an algorithm written in the `awk` language. Nothing fancy, most `awk` programs look more or less like this.

Answer (score 0):

With awk there might be a more elegant solution but you can have:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n?name=";FS="\nvalue="} {if($2) printf "%s=%s\n",$1,$2}' inputs.txt
```

`RS="\n?name="` says that the record separator is `name=`

`FS="\nvalue="` says that the field separator for each record is `value=`

`if($2)` says to only proceed the printf is the second field exists